# Changing the header name of pop out box

Tags: html, grails, popup

I'm not sure if this question is being asked, but I can't find any related post about this.
I actually created at pop out box after pressing a submit button so that I can create a user, however the pop out box looks like this

[image: Pop up]

This is the code of it

```
 <g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="createUser" class="btn_gray_large" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.cancel.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');"/>
```

I want to change the "The page at localhost:8080 says:" part into something else.
Is there anyway i can change that? By the way I'm using gsp grails and groovy to do this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This a browser default behavior you cant change this.

Comment: oh my, okay thank you so much for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change it (for security reasons), but you can make your own using something like [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) or [jQuery Alert Dialogs](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) if you use jQuery, or the [Javascript confirm dialog](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm) for vanilla js.